# Question about 3rd Normal Form

Tags: entity-relationship, relational, relational-database, third-normal-form

The following table :

```
EmpId  State   Zip
1       FL   342008
2       CA   342001
```

is not in 3rd normal form because
State is dependent on the primary
key(EmpId) transitively.

So, if I break it like this :
(EmpId,State)  (State,PIN)

it's in 3NF.

I could also break it like : 
(EmpId,State) (EmpId,PIN)
and it will again be in 3NF.

But in the second case,
there is redundancy of information, for
e.g.

```
1  FL
2  FL

1 342008
2 342008
```

Which property does the second decomposition violate?

Comment: By "PIN" do you mean the "Zip" column?

Comment: Is this homework? If so please tag it as such.

Comment: This is not homework. I am educating myself on databases by self-study.

Answer (score 1):

As already said, there is redundancy because the State can be inferred by the ZIP Code, hence, you should have your tables in this way:

```
EmpId Zip
1     342008

Zip    State
342008 FL
```

Always think on what depends on what. Of course, there is already an [standard process to normalize based on set theory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form). [This](http://www.bkent.net/Doc/simple5.htm#label3.2) could help you too.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly address your question, but, strictly speaking, the state column is redundant, because it can be derived from the ZIP code (although you're showing six-digit ZIP codes, which aren't standard in the USA.) You could break the table down by EmpID and ZIP, leaving State by itself in a lookup table.

Answer (score 0):

To directly address the question asked, the violated property is FFD (full functional dependency on the key).